# How to get user input while Multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium, user-input, python-multiprocessing, eoferror

I am trying to run multiple selenium instances in which I need to enter captchas, but I am a beginner in multiprocessing.

So while running and its time to give input it shows an error:

> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Here is an example of the code I am running:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import multiprocessing

def first():
    chromedriver = "C:\chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driver.set_window_size(1000, 1000)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    captcha1 = input("in1: ")
    print(inn)

def sec():
    chromedriver = "C:\chromedriver"
    driverr = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driverr.set_window_size(1000, 1000)
    driverr.get('https://www.google.com/')
    captcha2 = input("in2: ")
    print(ins)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=first)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sec)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Not only do I need to know how to give input but in this instance the **'captcha2'** input would be needed first, so the **'captcha1'** would have to wait until **'captcha2'** is given...

Answer (score 0):

You need to send **messages** requesting user input back to the main process so that it (and only it) can ask the user about them.  The simplest way to do this is probably to create a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) object for the requests (so that the main process can listen to **all** children) and a `Pipe` for **each** process for the answers.  Each request would of course be labeled with an identifier for the process sending it so that the response could be sent to the right place.